# Contentstack: Can’t Edit Properties of URL Field

Tags: content-management-system, headless-cms

Using the Contentstack CMS, I have always been able to edit Properties for the URL field for any Content Type, but never had any use for it. Now I thought I would have a use for it and wanted to check the options, but when I edit the Content Type in “Content Type Builder”, the URL field is grayed out and doesn’t respond to clicks.

I think that I have always had global admin, so I don’t think it could be a permissions issue. Do I need to change a setting somewhere or something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the Content Type as Single or Multiple? Editing properties for the URL field doesn’t make sense for Single Content Types.

Comment: Ugh…I guess I hadn’t created a Content Type in a while. Why do they even have Single Content Types, and why would they make that option the default?

Answer (score 0):

Per your followup comment -- A Singleton (Single Content Types) is really to allow one and only one (1) entry (e.g. Home Page).  You may not want content editors to be able to create multiple content pages.  So, you have a choice to make it a single entry content type or multiple entries content type.

See:  https://www.contentstack.com/docs/developers/create-content-types/single-vs-multiple-content-types/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1XwJ.png)